# Display image from file input in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I display an image which is chosen from a file input and display it in a table? The image is not displayed in the table column. It shows the `alt` attribute value.

```js
var tabData = []
var b;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var name = $('#uname').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();

    function readURL(input) { //here image chosse function
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          b = $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result); //image loaded from file
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function() {
      readURL(this);
    });
    
    if (name == "" || date == "") {
      alert("please fill fileds")
    } else {
      var tblObj = {
        Name: name,
        Date: date,
        Image: b
      } //where b is image varibale which is choose from file input.
      tabData.push(tblObj);
      var data = '';
      $('table').empty();
      tabData.forEach(element => {
        data = '<tr><td>' + element.Name + '</td><td>' + element.Date + '</td><td>' + '<img src="' + element.Image + '" alt="image"/>' + '</td></tr>'; //I want to show image in table third column but it can not show image it display alt attribute value  
        $('table').append(data);
      });
      $('form').trigger("reset")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#">
    Name:<input type="text" id="uname"> Date
    <input type="date" id="date"> Image:
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />

    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="output">
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

**Display error**

[Display not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI3v6.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you placed the code which handles the image selection within the `button` click handler - where it won't be called until after you first attempt to submit the form.

To fix the problem, move the `#imgInp` change handler logic to sit directly within the document.ready handler:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#imgInp").change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });

  $('button').click(function() {
    // other logic not relevant to the issue...
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#">
    Name:<input type="text" id="uname"> Date
    <input type="date" id="date"> Image:
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />

    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="output">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Note that `b` would be a jQuery object, not the base64 image source string as you seem to be expecting. If you need to retrieve that string, set `b = e.target.result` directly.